# How can I read all CSV files from a zipped folder using R data.table fread() function, preprocess, and add a column with original file name to result?

Tags: r, shell, csv, data.table

I have a zipped folder with a number of `CSV` files that have the same layout. I am reading those files after pre-processing using a `shell` script that retains the first four columns. I am using `data.table` `fread()` package and returning one data frame as such:

```
library(data.table)
 
# Create sample CSV files and zip them in a folder
df1 <- data.frame(a = seq(1,16,by=2), b = LETTERS[1:8], x= month.abb[1:8], y = sample(10:20,8, replace = TRUE), z=letters[1:8])
df2 <- data.frame(a = seq(1,32,by=4), b = LETTERS[9:16], x= month.abb[3:10], y = sample(10:20,8, replace = TRUE), z=letters[9:16])
df3 <- data.frame(a = seq(1,8,by=1), b = LETTERS[17:24], x= month.abb[5:12], y = sample(10:20,8, replace = TRUE), z=letters[17:24])
 
write.csv(df1, "file1.csv", row.names=FALSE)
write.csv(df2, "file2.csv", row.names=FALSE)
write.csv(df3, "file3.csv", row.names=FALSE)
 
zip("files.zip", c("file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv"))

# Unzip, pre-process, and read into R with fread() 
fread_files <-
  fread(
    cmd = "unzip -p -a files.zip | cut -d ',' -f 1-4",
    sep = ",",
    header = TRUE,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
    fill = TRUE) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  filter(a != "a")
```

My output looks good:

```
>fread_files
 
    a b   x  y
1   1 A Jan 14
2   3 B Feb 17
3   5 C Mar 16
4   7 D Apr 12
5   9 E May 18
6  11 F Jun 11
7  13 G Jul 17
8  15 H Aug 12
9   1 I Mar 13
10  5 J Apr 17
11  9 K May 20
12 13 L Jun 15
13 17 M Jul 12
14 21 N Aug 16
15 25 O Sep 16
16 29 P Oct 18
17  1 Q May 20
18  2 R Jun 15
19  3 S Jul 18
20  4 T Aug 15
21  5 U Sep 17
22  6 V Oct 16
23  7 W Nov 11
24  8 X Dec 10
```

Now I am trying to add a column that has the original filename to be able to track where my data is coming from. My desired output should look something like this:

```
>fread_files

    a b   x  y filename
1   1 A Jan 14 file1.csv
2   3 B Feb 17 file1.csv
3   5 C Mar 16 file1.csv
4   7 D Apr 12 file1.csv
5   9 E May 18 file1.csv
6  11 F Jun 11 file1.csv
7  13 G Jul 17 file1.csv
8  15 H Aug 12 file1.csv
9   1 I Mar 13 file2.csv
10  5 J Apr 17 file2.csv
11  9 K May 20 file2.csv
12 13 L Jun 15 file2.csv
13 17 M Jul 12 file2.csv
14 21 N Aug 16 file2.csv
15 25 O Sep 16 file2.csv
16 29 P Oct 18 file2.csv
17  1 Q May 20 file3.csv
18  2 R Jun 15 file3.csv
19  3 S Jul 18 file3.csv
20  4 T Aug 15 file3.csv
21  5 U Sep 17 file3.csv
22  6 V Oct 16 file3.csv
23  7 W Nov 11 file3.csv
24  8 X Dec 10 file3.csv
```

I tried a few approaches by adding another pipe and `awk` or `sed` statement to the `shell` script without much success because I am a lot more versed in `R` than `shell`. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative is to read the files in individually (repeated calls to `unzip`, unfortunately) and allow `rbindlist` to assign the filename column.

```r
lapply(setNames(nm = unzip("files.zip", list = TRUE)$Name),
       function(fn) fread(cmd = paste("unzip -p -a files.zip", fn, "| cut -d, -f1-4"))) %>%
  rbindlist(idcol = "filename")
#      filename     a      b      x     y
#        <char> <int> <char> <char> <int>
#  1: file1.csv     1      A    Jan    12
#  2: file1.csv     3      B    Feb    13
#  3: file1.csv     5      C    Mar    16
#  4: file1.csv     7      D    Apr    10
#  5: file1.csv     9      E    May    10
#  6: file1.csv    11      F    Jun    11
#  7: file1.csv    13      G    Jul    14
#  8: file1.csv    15      H    Aug    14
#  9: file2.csv     1      I    Mar    13
# 10: file2.csv     5      J    Apr    12
# ---                                    
# 15: file2.csv    25      O    Sep    14
# 16: file2.csv    29      P    Oct    19
# 17: file3.csv     1      Q    May    15
# 18: file3.csv     2      R    Jun    15
# 19: file3.csv     3      S    Jul    11
# 20: file3.csv     4      T    Aug    14
# 21: file3.csv     5      U    Sep    20
# 22: file3.csv     6      V    Oct    18
# 23: file3.csv     7      W    Nov    18
# 24: file3.csv     8      X    Dec    13
```

One bonus of this approach is that it does not corrupt the `int`-quality of columns `a` and `y` (which are going to be `character` in your case).

Answer (score 0):

I got your desired output with an `lapply` and a `transform`. I put the file names in a vector to be able to use later. Using the `unzip` function in side the `fread` function you can read the file with it being inside the zip file. The first part of the `transform` is for reading the current file from the zip and then the second part is for adding the column with the filename.

```
csvFiles <- c("file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv")
zip("files.zip", csvFiles)

df1 <- do.call(bind_rows, lapply(csvFiles, function(X) 
    transform(fread(unzip("files.zip", X), 
                sep = ",", 
                header = TRUE, 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                fill = TRUE,
                select = c(1,2,3,4)), 
          filename = X)))

View(df1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. In the real world (not mockup sample data I supplied) it is crucial to me to preprocess the data before reading into `R` because data after the 4th column is unstructured and of variable length. `fread()` as well as other `data.table` functions throw an error if I don't first preprocess in `UNIX`. Using `select()` has not worked. Can your solution be edited to include a preprocessing step?

Comment: If you're using different column names each cycle but still only need the first four columns consistently, you can give `select` the column positions instead of the column names

Comment: That is not an issue. In order to `select()` R has to read the data first. But it throws an error because it does not accept variable number of columns and lack of headers. I tried every R solution to select a subset of data without attempting to read it first (which it cannot do and throws an error.) Preprocessing in `UNIX` was the only solution I found.

Comment: I just ran it as I have it and got the first four columns without using the column names. I also have the column names on the data.table

Comment: Column names are not an issue. The issue is that in production, all the data after the fourth column is unstructured, and `data.table` cannot ingest it. I must preprocess the data before reading it into R. I understand that it works on the mockup data I supplied. In addition, in production, there are more preprocessing steps I have not included in a simplified example. For instance, I have quoted text with commas. `fread()` throws an error while trying to read it as a comma-delimited file because it thinks that some rows (ones that have commas in some fields) have more columns than others.

Comment: Would you be able to mockup an example of that?